# I have a Flutter code of about 2000 line and i only used 5 widgets repeatedly Column, Row, Container and Elevated Button but Give error

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints

BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width.The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=-0.8, 0.0<=h<=Infinity; NOT NORMALIZED)
This error is showing when i run my project

previously it runs good normally but i downloaded the project from Github and now it is not working same Code as Previous

Comment: can you include sample code that will reproduce the same error? More about [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).